# Local variable 'cb_answer' value is not used

Tags: python, chatbot

I am trying to build a simple chatbot, but it says "Local variable 'cb_answer' value is not used" for multiple states and "cb_answers"'s. Hence the chatbot doesn't give me an answer, when I run the program. I attached a screenshot from the code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQKOv.png)

Comment: The return should be indented one times less.

Comment: It is recommended to just paste your code here rather than showing a picture. It is easier to work with (answer) generally.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302, but still I do not get any answer

Answer (score 2):

`Local variable 'cb_answer' value is not used` is a **warning** not an **error**.
The problem is that you are creating a variable inside of your ifs. You won't be able to access it outside of the if you created it in. To fix this put:

```
cb_answer = None
state = None
```

At the top of your function.

And like @luk2302 mentioned the return should be one less indented.

Comment: I did both. But the chatbot still doesn't give any response..

Comment: If you did exactly what I told you then I can't help you, because the problem is probably in your code somewhere. It has likely nothing to do with the current question.

Comment: Try printing the state, cb_answer, keywordlist before returning and see if you get what you expect to get.

Comment: Hmm, can we link up maybe?